# Once I put a function into defer() in D3, the data structure inside console.log changed in other function

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

The following snippet is my code that will fetch data from csv file.

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, "sales.csv", function(d){
        //d.decade = d.decade.replace("-","_")
        //console.log('lalala')
    })
    .await(ready)
```

And then this is the function that will create bubble.

```
function ready(error,datapoints){
    console.log(datapoints)
    var circles = svg.selectAll(".artist")
    .data(datapoints)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class","artist")// the ".artist" will transform into class name in HTML
    .attr("r", function(d){
        return radiusScale(d.sales)
    })
    .attr("fill","lightblue")
    .on("click",function(d){
        console.log(d)
    })
    //.attr("cx",100)
    //.attr("cy",300)

    simulation.nodes(datapoints)
        .on('tick', ticked)

    function ticked(){
        circles
            .attr("cx",function(d){
                return d.x
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d){
                return d.y
            })
    }
}
```

The problem arise when I do console.log(dataset). Whenever I have:

```
function(d){
        d.decade = d.decade.replace("-","_")
    }
```

in my

```
.defer(d3.csv, "sales.csv", function(d){
        d.decade = d.decade.replace("-","_")
    })
```

the result in the console.log(datapoints) will be something like this:
[weird_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC242.png)

And if I remove

```
function(d){
        d.decade = d.decade.replace("-","_")
    }
```

and becomes:

```
defer(d3.csv, "sales.csv")
```

The result would be normal like this:
[normal_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vrqK.png)

Can someone explain to me why it is? And how to do data stemming in this case?

Comment: you have to return something from the row-function, add `return d;`

Comment: Thanks man! That helps A LOT!!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return d;` at the end of the function!